# Quick way to clear contents of qtablewidget

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a Qt application in Python 3.6.5 using PySide2 v5.6.0. This application is a tool to be used to label many tens of thousands of images for training neural networks and has a qtablewidget for viewing information pertaining to each image.

I have implemented filtering by label status/name/etc, and when a filter is applied, I am clearing the table with `mainWin.tableWidget.clearContents()` and re-populating it with the new entries. I have tested this on a few hundred images, and it clears the table in less than a second; however, when the details for more than a few thousand image files have been loaded into the table, the program hangs on the clearContents() method. I don't know if it will eventually finish, but I have waited over 30 minutes in some cases and it has never cleared the table. One of my testers has reported that if you do wait long enough, it will eventually filter on large data sets, but obviously this is not a viable solution.

Trying `clear()` and `setRowCount(0)` give the same result.

The only thing special about the table is that I have a few signals hooked up to it to display images when a user clicks on a new row, but that is about it, and when I disabled those, it still would hang.

Here is my question: is there some way to quickly clear the rows or maybe filter them with some built in qtablewidget function?

Also, I feel I should point out that I am not storing image data in the table. All that I am storing in each cell is about 10-30 characters of text. Images are loaded from the disk when they are selected and are not stored in RAM.

Thank you.

Comment: So far, I have a workable solution which, now that I know about the feature, is preferable anyway. Using the following:

`tableWidget.setRowHidden(row, True)`

works very well for filtering, doing so in a few seconds for 30,000 rows. It still takes forever to empty the table of all 30,000 rows when closing the dataset to load another, but I suppose for the time being the users can close the program and open it again since that is a lot faster.